# Show in console a text read from file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a file in Qt and then show it in console, this is my mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ifstream F("datos.txt");
    int id;
    string name;
    int age;

    while(F >> id >> name >> age){                         /*reading the file*/
        cout << id << ", " << name << ", " << age << endl; /*this doesn't work*/
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work, I googled it but I just found other method to read files from Qt. I need this specific method but if this is not possible, tell me what is the short way to read a file with a lot of lines in this format:

```
123123123 aname 123123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pasted is printing the contents of the file `datos.txt` into `stdout`. Just make sure the file is placed in the directory the program is ran in.

also this *specific method* is not related to **Qt**, this is using the **Standard C++ library**.

Comment: Ty so much, was the file location ._.
 The file must be in the folder named "build-myprojectname-Desktop_Qt_5_6_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug" and not the folder that contains the .cpp files.